# Why I can't edit "Your Communities" list in stackexchange.com and Area 51?

Tags: support, area-51, stackexchange.com, communities-list

I can edit "YOUR COMMUNITIES" in the upper left drop-down menu from any of my communities: (e.g. [graphicdesign.stackexchange.com](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com))

> [image: Graphic Design]

But in [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/) portal there's no "edit" link:

> [image: Stack Exchange]

Why is that and how can I edit the list in http://stackexchange.com portal?

Comment: Status By Design.

Comment: no-repro, even at page of this question, I am able to see the edit button in menu.

Comment: @DroidDev: go to http://stackexchange.com instead and try it there. Meta is a full site with accounts, so of course you can edit the list here.

Comment: @DroidDev That's because we are in the Meta community. Go to http://stackexchange.com/ and you will see what I am talking about.

Comment: Fair question, the cause is different codebase for stackexchange.com - the top bar in there is just a "clone" of the real top bar, so whatever code responsible for editing wasn't copied.

Comment: @Kate doesn't make much sense to decline a support question, but we can amend that by changing to [tag:feature-request]... what do you think? This would render the existing answer here pointless though, so maybe better start new question, focusing on asking to add that feature instead of asking "why not".

Comment: well instead of a declined answer I would settle for an accurate "because we don't want to / it would be too difficult" answer. The existing one is not correct even though it's accepted. I would prefer an "you know what we have no good reason we're going to fix this" answer

Comment: @KateGregory I don't really want to post an answer for the sake of posting an answer... **the accepted one, especially after the edit that included my comment, is correct** - we aren't going to add a private API to edit this list from A51/chat. Strictly speaking, *might* do it from stackexchange.com since we just did some refactoring on it, so hitting the central DB that houses this info is theoretically possible now whereas it wasn't before... but we're a ways off from that and, if/when we come to that, the whole "network profile" thing needs love, so it'd probably be a bigger project.

Comment: @KateGregory P.S. "We're a ways off from that" = "more refactoring is needed, and someone has to actually remember that the network profile exists". I'll try? No promises. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your Stackexchange.com account is not mutable; you cannot edit it. It is reflected from an account on one of the Stack Exchange community sites, like https://english.stackexchange.com/ or https://stackoverflow.com/ instead, and copied across as a central reference page.

As such, you cannot edit the 'my communities' list on Stackexchange.com either. There is no actual account to store the change in.

Sure, it is possible to add editing views to Stackexchange.com to edit the reflected info, but as [Anna Lear points out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231971/why-i-cant-edit-your-communities-list-in-stackexchange-com/231972#comment772266_231972), there just isn't enough call for this to justify the complexity.

Comment: I don't think it's attached to specific account, the list is same on all sites. More like different codebase, and they didn't copy the relevant code over there.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: right, they rolled out a new feature across all sites but left out *just* the edit link on Stackexchange.com?

Comment: The new top bar is in Area51 as well but also without the edit link. They just made a shallow copy of the code as far as I can tell.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I see that Area51 also doesn't support editing the communities link; the Area51 stack barely supports connecting with the rest of the network, looks like the account there also doesn't support changing the list.

Comment: Philosophically, this is mostly it. The "there's no account" part isn't really true, though. The practical reason was that we didn't want to replicate every route that powers the editor on the Q&A sites to allow for them to be called via internal APIs from se.com, Area 51, and chat. There's just not enough use on any of those to justify the added complexity at the moment.