# How to leave a website?

Tags: discussion, support, android-app

I don't want **3D printing** to show up in 'my websites'. I am using the Android app. How can I remove that site?

Comment: You did find the [edit button](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231971/why-i-cant-edit-your-communities-list-in-stackexchange-com-and-area-51)?

Comment: @rene I am using the android app

Comment: The android app may not have the full functionality of the main site

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290092/how-do-i-hide-my-accounts-on-a-specific-stack-exchange-site/290093#290093

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to your profile on any SE *website* on the *desktop view* - the Android app does not have this functionality, and I can't find it in mobile view. Go to "edit profile and settings" and you can hide communities there.

If it's an account you have never used before, [you can simply delete it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account). Once again, no mobile UI I can find.